# mediawiki user can't create his user page

Tags: mediawiki, configuration

I got a MediaWiki, and almost all is working fine, but when i try to edit a page with an user, the page `?title=User:{username}"

I got this message

> There is currently no text in this page. You can search for this page title in other pages, or search the related logs, but you do not have permission to create this page.

Which `$wgGroupPermissions` should i use to allow an user to edit only his own user page without being able to edit other pages & content ?

Answer (score 2):

`edit` and `createpage` are needed to edit a userpage (see [list of permissions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights#List_of_permissions)). There is no core permission to differentiate own pages from others' pages, but extensions might add one (e.g. [UserPageEditProtection](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserPageEditProtection) does, although it does not seem to be up-to-date).

Comment: and then he can create and edit any pages, the goal is to have only rights for his user page

Comment: A good idea to specify that in the question :)

Comment: yup sorry about it ! that s why i updated it, i asked on wiki IRC and it seems to requier a hook to do this, i will check about it later, first i have some more urgent task. Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: That's probably [userCan](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/userCan).